# Reuse SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing

How I can Reuse the subclass SwingWorker for more than one use, without creating a new subclass SwingWorker and change in DoInBackround() to open a different JFrame/JDialog ?

```
class Loading extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Lambda")
    public Void doInBackground() throws InterruptedException {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                d.setVisible(true);
                new Taxi_Summary().setVisible(true);
               //here i want to open a new JFrames/JDialogs when a button is pressed

            }
        });

        Thread.sleep(2000);//2000 millis = 2 seconds

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void done() {
        d.dispose();

    }
}
```

Comment: You know, you'd actually be better off using a Swing `Timer`.  As to your question/.  Pass it a reference of the frame you want to close

Comment: Thank u I'll try that, but how about SwingWorker is there any way that I can make it reusable as I mentioned before, without having to repeat the same code over and over, for just a simple change in DoInBackround() ??

Comment: From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#execute()) - *"Note: SwingWorker is only designed to be executed once. Executing a SwingWorker more than once will not result in invoking the doInBackground method twice."* - So, no, you can't "reuse" it.  But you can make it more flexible, by providing a constructor which takes a reference to the frame you want to control

Comment: Ok, I got it I'll try to figure out something to do the trick. Thanks